# Bold entries in table with S column type

Tags: tables, siunitx

Inspired by the following post [\bfseries and alignment in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117161/bfseries-and-alignment-in-table), I want to create a table where some of the entries are highlighted in bold, and further, the numbers should be aligned on the dot. I defined the boldentry command as desribed on the post, but for some reason the numbers are not perfectly aligned in this case. What is the problem in the code below?

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt,authoryear,longnamesfirst]{memoir}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}
\newcommand{\MS}[1] {
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\boldentry}[2]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{S[table-format=#1,
                mode=text,
                text-rm=\fontseries{b}\selectfont
               ]}{#2}}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}

\begin{table}
\scriptsize
\caption{A caption}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{9}{S[table- 
    format=1.3]}}
\toprule
        & \MS{A} & \MS{B} & \MS{C} & \MS{D} & \MS{E} & \MS{F} & \MS{G} & 
          \MS{H} & \MS{I}\\
\midrule

     A & \boldentry{1.3}{1.004}&\boldentry{1.3}{1.000}&\boldentry{1.3} 
     {1.008}&\boldentry{1.3}{1.000}&\boldentry{1.3}{0.989}&\boldentry{1.3} 
     {1.008}&1.070  & \boldentry{1.3}{0.981}&1.025\\

     B & 1.025  & 1.012  & 1.016  & \boldentry{1.3}{1.000}&\boldentry{1.3} 
     {0.967}&\boldentry{1.3}{0.968}&\boldentry{1.3}{0.982}&\boldentry{1.3} 
     {0.961}&1.077\\

     C& 1.009  & 1.001  & 1.002  & 1.000  & 0.986  & 0.985  & 0.991  & 
     \boldentry{1.3}{0.973}&0.998\\

     D & 1.009  & 1.010  & 1.001  & 1.000  & 0.951  & 0.959  & 0.975  & 
     \boldentry{1.3}{0.931}&1.015\\
    \bottomrule

\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
\setlength\labelsep{0pt}
\scriptsize
\item A footnote  
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Observation: if you add `\scriptsize` to egreg's code in the [post you linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117168/108704), his table is not aligned either... It might be because at script size, bold numbers are actually significantly narrower than normal ones (it's even more visible with `\tiny`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

i remove your definition `\newcommand{\boldentry}[2]{...}`, add the package `etoolbox` for robust new command `\B` which is used to indicate the cells that have bold faced numbers. LL CHanges in comparison to your mwe are indicated in code by `% <--`:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt,authoryear,longnamesfirst]{memoir}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % instead of \MS. you can still use your command ...
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{etoolbox}           % <--
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % <--
\robustify\bfseries             % <--
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}    % <--


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \small
    \caption{A caption}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
        l
    *{9}{S[detect-weight,   % <--
           mode=text,       % <--
           table-format=1.3]}}
\toprule
    & \mcc{A}   & \mcc{B}   & \mcc{C}   & \mcc{D}   & \mcc{E}
    & \mcc{F}   & \mcc{G}   & \mcc{H}   & \mcc{I}       \\
\midrule
A   & \B 1.004  & \B 1.000  & \B 1.008  & \B 1.000  & \B 0.989
    & \B 1.008  &    1.070  & \B 0.981  &    1.025      \\
B   &   1.025   &    1.012  &    1.016  & \B 1.000  & \B 0.967
    & \B 0.968  & \B 0.982  & \B 0.961  &    1.077      \\
C   &    1.009  &    1.001  &    1.002  &    1.000  &    0.986
    &    0.985  &    0.991  & \B 0.973  &    0.998      \\
D   &    1.009  &    1.010  &    1.001  &    1.000  & 0.951
    &    0.959  &    0.975  & \B 0.931  &    1.015      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
\setlength\labelsep{0pt}
\scriptsize
\item A footnote
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @mico, ups, i forgot to add two more lines for boldface text. corrected now. thank you very much for pointing me on this.